# Remove special characters from a string with a condition

Tags: c#, .net

I have a string as below-

```cs
"This is <h2>a place/h2>
<p>You know its a good place!</p>
<ul>
    <li>Booked your ticket #20130114074912_AN3P703C on Monday, January 14</li>
</ul>"
```

So, I want my string to be as follows

```
"This is a place
You know its a good place.
Booked your ticket #20130114074912_AN3P703C on Monday, January 14"
```

Comment: `InnerText` of the root node? PS: It might help if you have valid XML/HTML...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is the answer for you. [link](http://www.dotnetperls.com/remove-html-tags)

try this:

```
// <summary>
/// Remove HTML from string with Regex.
/// </summary>
public static string StripTagsRegex(string source)
{
   return Regex.Replace(source, "<.*?>", string.Empty);
}
```

Output:

```
Input:    <p>The <b>dog</b> is <i>cute</i>.</p>
Output:   The dog is cute.
```

Comment: The link is good, but include some relevant content from the linked page.

Comment: Link only answers are prone to becoming useless if the link is broken. Add some content from that page, or at least names of components/software to look for.

Comment: @gideon, I could just gave him the 3 lines as Thorsten did(by entering the link and copy paste) but i preferred that he will see the differences and choose the best one for him.

Comment: @Niranjan Kala, Thanks for the edit, for further time i will write my post like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove HTML tags from any string using the following method

```
static string StripHTML (string inputString)
{
  return Regex.Replace(inputString, "<.*?>", string.Empty);
}
```

Comment: Unless the tag has an attribute with a `>` in... (This also won't remove the malformed `/h2>`, although that may be a lost cause.)

Answer (score 0):

This would do the job in your case

```
String neededString = Regex.Replace(source, "<.*?>", string.Empty);
```

for more comcplicated string, that contains CSS, JavaScript node u can use the following

```
String neededStringRegex.Replace(subjectString, @"<(style|script)[^<>]*>.*?</\1>|</?[a-z][a-z0-9]*[^<>]*>|<!--.*?-->", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Download and reference the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), then call the following:

```
var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(input);
string output = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.InnerText;
```

This still won't remove your malformed `/h2>` tag, but it should handle a lot more HTML than a regular expression will.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
string input = "This is <h2> a place</h2><p>You know its a good place!</p><ul>    <li>Booked your ticket #20130114074912_AN3P703C on Monday, January 14</li></ul>";
input = Regex.Replace(input, "<.*?>", string.Empty);
```

This will find all strings enclosed in "<>" and replace it with "" or Empty String